# How to start a background function in Rust as I do in Go with goroutine?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust, I'm coming from Go.

With Go is very easy to start a function in a goroutine even if I return the parent one, example:

```golang
func doSomething() {
  // do something

  go func() {
    // do something longer
    // this doesn't block doSomething and also handles optional errors
  }()

  return // something
}
```

How can I do this in Rust?

Let's say I have this code:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    doSomething().await;
}

async fn doSomething() {
    // do something

    // How to start something longer here?
    // I don't want to block doSomething function here, this is only a background task I need to start.

    return // something
}
```

Comment: https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly. To `await` a `Future` in rust you must use syntax `future.await`. So your main function should look like this instead

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
  doSomething().await;
}
```

As for your main question `async` is non-blocking by design in rust. If a future is not ready to make progress it yields back to the scheduler and another future may run in the meantime. I guess that you want to spawn another *task* that would run *concurrently* to the `doSomething` future. To do that use [`tokio::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html) (since you are using tokio, other executors have their own functions). So your example could be rewritten this way:

```rust
async fn foo() {
    // does some work
}

async fn doSomething() {
    // do something

    tokio::spawn(async {
        foo().await;
    });

    return // something
}
```

If you are just starting learning async rust, then I would recommend reading Tokio's async [tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial).

Comment: Thank you! Is `tokio::spawn()` roughly the same as `go func()` in Go?

Comment: @FredHors I'm not very familiar with Go, but it seems to me that they are pretty similar.

Comment: @FredHors in the sense that the spawned task will not block the spawner task, and that both can run in parallel, yes. They have somewhat different capabilities though e.g. `tokio::spawn` returns a [`JoinHandle`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html) you can synchronise on (and like `thread::spawn` it can return a value), but it also requires that its parameter is `Send + 'static` and deals with Rust's usual ownership & borrowing.